# Change thumbnail image on rollover in the loop

Tags: javascript, wordpress, loops, thumbnails, rollover

I've got a question. I am working with wordpress and have a blog which posts are presented with thumbnails. I'd like those thumbnails change when you put your mouse on. The problem is that I want different images change thumbnails. basically, each thumbnail would have its unique rollover image. the problem is that i don't quite know how to attach js code to the loop. And how it should look like to create different rollover images for different posts
if i attach js code to the permalink, it will change all thumbnails into the same picture. 
also, i was told it is possible to do with jquery. is it worthy?
i was trying to be as clear as possible
any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could add a custom field to each of your posts called `hoverImg`, which value is the link to the image you want to use as a rollover image.

Then you fetch the link in the loop, and add it:

```
<?php $hover_image = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'hoverImg', true); ?>

<img class="hover-img" src="<?php echo $hover_image; ?>" />
```

this image should be initially invisible, and positioned as an overlay to your thumbnail. Then just show it on hover with jquery.

Since I dont have your image, I've created a jsFiddle with two divs, one representing your thumbnail, and one representing your rollover image to mimic the effect:

http://jsfiddle.net/9Xa92/1/

You should just replace the `<div class="hover-img"></div>` in the jsfiddle with the actual thumbnail image (created above).

Comment: I managed to insert custom fields and function into the loop,but now my hoverImg is standing right next to the thumbnail and it is visible. it might be due to the fact i use < ul > to put thumbnails into certain locations
another thing is that i dont know much of jquery so i ended up with such a code (which is probably wrong)  
`jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('img.wp-post-image').hover(
function(){
    jQuery('this').attr("src","hoverImg");
}, function(){
    jQuery('this').attr('src','wp-post-image');
});`
i use jQuery instead of $,cause i read WP doesnt recognise $

Comment: Wordpress works fine with $ - where did you read otherwise?
This should not be quoted, so change JQuery('this') to $(this) and go from there